# How do I use join clause to only check whether row exists?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables like this:

```
// Posts
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
| id |  title  |    content      |  amount  |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
| 1  | title1  | content1        | NULL     |
| 2  | title2  | content2        | 1000     |
| 3  | title3  | content3        | 5000     |
| 4  | title4  | content4        | NULL     |
| 5  | title5  | content5        | 2000     |
+----+---------+-----------------+----------+
//                                 ^ NULL means that question is free


// Money_Paid
+----+---------+---------+
| id | user_id | post_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  | 123     | 2       |
| 2  | 345     | 5       |
| 3  | 123     | 5       |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**All I'm trying to do:** Some of my posts aren't free and anybody wants to see them should pay their cost. Now I need a query to check current user paid the cost of that post or not? *(just for non-free post)*

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p WHERE id = :post_id
LEFT JOIN Money_Paid mp ON p.amount IS NOT NULL AND ...
```

---

Here is a few **examples**: *(based on current tables)*

```
$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 123, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//=> TRUE (the user of '123' can see this post because he paid post's cost)

$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 345, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//=> FALSE (the user of '345' cannot see this post because he didn't pay post's cost)

$stm->bindValue(":post_id", 5, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stm->bindValue(":user_id", 345, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//=> TRUE
```

---

**All I want of the query:** I want a column contains  `true` or `false` *(just for non-free posts)* to tells me current user paid the cost of current post or not. In other word:

There is a row in `Money_paid` table which `user_id = :user_id` => `true`

There isn't any row -> `false`

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you want as the output.

Comment: did you tried  JOIN Money_Paid mp ON p.amount IS NOT NULL AND mp.post_id = p.id AND  mp.user_id = :user_id ??

Comment: @GordonLinoff I did.

Comment: @GordonLinoff May you please tell me [which one is more better](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/03dbe6af820f93cb183c52905389f61e)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure I'm understanding your desired results, but here's a way to add a new column that can return true or false depending on whether the user has paid:

```
select *, 
    case when mp.id is not null then 'true' else 'false' end paid
from Posts p 
   left join Money_Paid mp ON mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id
where p.id = :post_id
```

Comment: emm, just onething, to check row is exist, should I use `count(1)`?

Comment: @stack -- that's what the `case` statement is doing for you.  Use that with the `outer join` and it will check if the row exists or not and return true or false accordingly.

Comment: Just may you please tell me [which one is more better](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/03dbe6af820f93cb183c52905389f61e) ?

Answer (score 0):

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts p
JOIN Money_Paid mp ON p.id = mp.post_id
WHERE mp.user_id = :user_id
AND p.id = :post_id
```

This will return the row if the user has paid for the content. And will return nothing if the user hasn't paid for the content.

Comment: Trust me, I know how I should pass current-user-id to the query.

Comment: @stack Sorry, didn't understand the question. Updated my answer with the correct query, let me know if it works. :)

Comment: Thank you for your update. But I really cannot use the ouptu of this query in PHP to do what I need.

Comment: You can still check with an `if` statement if the result is true or false. It'll return true if there is a row and false if there is nothing. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

As i commented you may try  ( check where the join is)

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Money_Paid mp ON p.amount IS NOT NULL AND 
JOIN Money_Paid mp ON 
mp.post_id = p.id AND p.amount IS NOT NULL  AND mp.user_id = :user_id
WHERE 
id = :post_id
```

Bu also, you can list  them  all.

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p 
WHERE
p.amount IS  NULL 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN Money_Paid mp ON 
p.amount IS NOT NULL AND
mp.post_id = p.id AND 
mp.user_id = :user_id
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Posts p 
WHERE
p.amount IS  NULL 
OR p.id in ( 
SELECT post_id FROM Money_Paid mp
WHERE 
p.amount IS NOT NULL AND
mp.user_id = :user_id
)
```

Comment: Why `INNER JOIN`? Why not `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Because we know the post and the user, no need for a false outer join. its 0 or 1 with inner you can avoid null data

Answer (score 0):

if you want column that will tell you if you can view post or not try something like this (left join and if statement)

```
select 
    p.*, 
    if(p.amount is not null, if(mp.user_id is not null, 1, 0), 1) as canView 
from Posts p
left join Money_Paid mp on mp.post_id = p.id and mp.user_id = :user_id;
```

if column canView is 1 then user can view post otherwise he can't. You can also  check for specific post just add `where p.id = :post_id`